# React input value doesnt work with states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have weird error. When i try change my input value with a state its not working but if i write my state some void place so its start changing value. Why its being like that ? My codes :

```
  <Form
    className="mt-4"
    layout="vertical"
    requiredMark="hidden"
    name="basic"
    form={form}
    onFinish={onFinish}
    onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
  >
    <Form.Item
      name="Name"
      label="Başlık"
      style={{ width: 400 }}
      rules={[{ required: true, message: "Lütfen Başlık Giriniz!" }]}
    >
      <Input
        id="IDTitle"
        placeholder="Başlık"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item name="Url" label="URL" style={{ width: 400 }}>
{titleData} // if i write it its working. But if i delete that row its not shows or update value.
      <Input placeholder="Url" disabled value={titleData}></Input>
    </Form.Item>
     
     
      <Button
        type="primary"
        className="submitButton float-right"
        htmlType="submit"
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>

const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const data = e.target.value;
    console.log(data);
    setTitleData(toEnglishChar(data));
  };
```

How can i solve it ? Thanks for all replies! I dont know why its happening like that but i tried everything i can do. I tried change antd input with default input too but it didnt work too. Thanks for all replies !!

Comment: This code snippet looks incomplete. Please post all relevant code. Also please tag appropriately. This is either React, Angular, OR Vue, not all 3

Comment: Its react project with Ant Design components. I will edit my codes now 1 minute. Thanks for warning.

Comment: Please share the whole component code

Comment: @User10 I edit my code.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I edit my code.

Comment: If the Input is wrapped in a Form it behaves differently

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim but why its working if i add {titleData} to somewhere? So what can i do for make it update?

Comment: @UğurcanUçar: Could you perhaps turn this into a runnable example, even using an external site like CodeSandbox?  That way we could observe and interact with the behavior you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Change `onChange` event like the following:

```
<Input
  id="IDTitle"
  placeholder="Başlık"
  onChange={e => handleInputChange(e)}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply brother! But its still same result. İts not updating without my state on void.